# Terraform aws_amplify_app module create-app responds with There was an issue setting up your repository

Tags: terraform, bitbucket, aws-amplify, access-token

I can't seem to create aws_amplify_app from terraform. I'm getting

`Error: error creating Amplify App (test-amplify-uat): BadRequestException: There was an issue setting up your repository. Please try again later.({"type": "error", "error": {"message": "You may not have access to this repository or it no longer exists in this workspace. If you think this repository exists and you have access, make sure you are authenticated."}})`

I followed the token creation from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/integrate-a-bitbucket-repository-with-aws-amplify-using-aws-cloudformation.html

I've noted that *Use accessToken for GitHub repositories only. To authorize access to a repository provider such as Bitbucket or CodeCommit, use oauthToken.*

I don't to use CF but TF. When I go to Bitbucket to look at the authorised app, I do see my app being authorised as per instructions.

So my tf

```
resource "aws_amplify_app" "main" {
  name         = "${var.name}-amplify-${var.environment}"
  repository   = var.git_repository
  oauth_token  = var.oauth_token ...
```

Has anyone used tf with bitbucket and deploying to aws-amplify. I would have thought the token is authorisation to access the repo. I get the same error if I use incognito to access the repo.

It shouldn't this hard but I must have missed something. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the values of your variables?

Comment: git repository is the repository containing the react code. BTW, this all worked in github, just moving to bitbucket. 

oauth_token was create from the link above

Comment: Likely not an answer to your question, but I wanted to note that the use of `oauth_token` instead of `access_token` when using a Bitbucket repository is what I was missing - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my git-repository variable. I had it as

https://admin@bitbucket.org/myworkspace/frontend.git

which does work on a git clone. Had to change it to

https://bitbucket.org/myworkspace/frontend.git

Answer (score 0):

When integrating AWS Amplify with Bitbucket, you need to create an OAuth Consumer and utilize the Client ID and Secret to generate an OAuth token. Here is a functional solution using Terraform:

**bitbucket.tf**

```
data "http" "bitbucket_oauth_token" {
  url    = "https://${var.bitbucket_oauth_client_id}:${var.bitbucket_oauth_secret}@bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token"
  method = "POST"

  request_headers = {
    Content-Type : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Accept = "application/json"
  }

  request_body = "grant_type=client_credentials"
}
```

**amplify.tf**

```
resource "aws_amplify_app" "app" {
  name        = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}"
  repository  = "https://bitbucket.org/${var.bitbucket_workspace}/${var.project_name}"
  oauth_token = jsondecode(data.http.bitbucket_oauth_token.response_body).access_token
  # etc...
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "environment" {
  description = "The environment for this infrastructure"
  type        = string
  default     = "development"
}

variable "project_name" {
  description = "The project name to the Bitbucket repository name"
  type        = string
}

variable "bitbucket_workspace" {
  description = "Bitbucket workspace"
  type        = string
}

variable "bitbucket_oauth_client_id" {
  description = "Bitbucket OAuth consumer client ID"
  type        = string
}

variable "bitbucket_oauth_secret" {
  description = "Bitbucket OAuth consumer secret"
  type        = string
}
```

**Reference**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/integrate-a-bitbucket-repository-with-aws-amplify-using-aws-cloudformation.html